# Drag-n-Drop NSTabViewItem

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstabview

In my application, we have NSTabViewItem inside NSTab , and there could be More then one NSTabViewItem are possible,
To Support one of the feature, we need to support Drag-n-Drop in NSTabViewItem, i.e. i should be able to rearrange NSTabViewItem and if its dropped else where another control of our application, then some particular action should happen,

I went through documentation but didn't find any support for it, but it seems to be quite obvious use - case ,

Am i missing something

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I *never* saw such a behaviour. I would give you the advice to use an NSTabView without tabs and to use [AMButtonBar](http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-code.php) for example in order to select a tabviewitem with `selectTabViewItemAtIndex:` programmatically. You could adopt `NSDraggingSource` and `NSDraggingDestination` protocols then within this code to make the elements (of the button bar and not the table view itself) rearrangeable.